# Pulling Registry Values not working

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I have just started learning automation....

Am looking to query below registry values to a test file with a date.

[eRegistry values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DESiy.png)

I have written below script; however, I think this is missing some logic hence not able to get append value for each registry string,

```vb
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Const ForAppending = 2
Set objfso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objFile = objfso.OpenTextFile("C:\SWSetup\abc.txt", 8, true)
'Set filestreamOUT = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\Test.txt,8,true)
strComputer = "."

'strPath = "C:\SWSetup\abc.txt"
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\SAT"
strValueName1 = "Bcore"
strValueName = "GG"
strValueName = "Graph"
strValueName = "MEM"
strValueName = "PHD"
strValueName = "PHDk"
strValueName = "Pro"

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

'oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue

oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue,strValueName1
objFile.WriteLine (Now)
objfile.WriteLine strValue
objfile.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a much simpler way.

Use `WScript.Shell` Object to read values from registry.

Created a sample for you.

Modify it accordingly

I tested on my system.

I am seeing the expected results.

```
'DECLARE A FILE SYSTEM OBJECT
Set objfso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objFile = objfso.OpenTextFile("C:\\Users\\<<YOUR USER NAME>>\\desktop\\abc.txt", 8, true)

'CREATE A SHELL OBJECT TO READ REGISTRY
Dim WSHShell, value
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


'READ REGISTRY VARIABLES
value = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAT\GG")
objFile.WriteLine (value & "  " & Now)

value = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAT\Graph")
objFile.WriteLine (value & "  " & Now)

value = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAT\MEM")
objFile.WriteLine (value & "  " & Now)

value = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAT\PHD")
objFile.WriteLine (value & "  " & Now)


'CLEAR THE OBJECTS
objfile.Close
set WSHShell = nothing
```

To get the key name perfectly:

- Run the registry and search for "SAT" in your case.
- Select it and right click your mouse.
- You can see "Copy Key Name".
- Select it.
- Now paste it in some notepad.
- Then append the "value" names to it. ( in your case GG MEM etc..)